# Debian 6 Gnome black screen after boot

Tags: debian, gnome, boot, ati

I installed Debian a few weeks ago, and the last time I ran `apt-get update`, I think it updated something **xorg/xserver**, not sure.

Since then i get a black screen after boot.
If I go into recovery mode I need to input the root password for maintenance, then I get a console.

I have an `ATI Radeon HD 7800` and I installed the newest catalyst driver from the ATI website.

I checked `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` but couldn't find any errors (EE)

If I run `startx`, I just get a black screen, gdm3 gives me this error:`(gdm3:1308): WARNING: Couldn't connect to system bus: Failed to connect to socket /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket: No such file or directory`.

What to do?

Answer (score 1):

You might have also updated other kernel modules related to your graphics chipset. Without knowing what you have done exactly it is hard to tell.

### Here are some ideas

```
1. read logs while system is running
```

after your system seems to be booted, press `CTRL + ALT + F1` to get tty1. Login and try reading your other error logs in `/var/log/`.

```
2. reinstall your video driver/module
```

I would also suggest reinstalling your graphics driver. This means you should install a command line browser like `lynx` or `w3m` then download and install your graphics driver/module.

http://support.amd.com/us/kbarticles/Pages/AMDCatalyst131ProprietaryLinuxGraphicsDriverReleaseNotes.aspx

After reading some logs and reinstalling your driver, you will at least have some insight on what to do next.

```
3. use fallback vesa driver
```

Another option is using the fallback `vesa` driver in your `xorg.conf` file. this will get the system up and running graphically on a basic level

Comment: I removed everything xorg/x11 with apt-get purge and installed it again. Now it works again. Thanks for your help!

Comment: no problem, did reading the log help? or did you just reinstall X11 first off?